# Upgrade Crystal Reports XI to 2011

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I am working on upgrading our version of Crystal Reports from Crystal Reports XI to Crystal Reports 2011.  We have a C# windows form application and we are currently using Visual Studio 2010.  I have installed the Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010.  This updated my references.  I have installed Crystal Reports Runtime engine for .net framework 4.0 (I have tried both the 32 bit and the 64 bit).

In our application, we run reports by using a report viewing form that supplies the crystal viewer with the path and connection info:

```
var crReportDocument = new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();
crReportDocument.Load(reportPath);
ReportUtilities.ApplyConnectionInfo(crReportDocument, _useReportServer);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crReportDocument;
crystalReportViewer1.Zoom(1);
```

When we publish the app currently with Crystal Reports XI we are able to have the prerequisites set to “Download prerequisites from the same location as my application”.  The only prerequisites are .net 4 framework and crystal reports runtime. I have moved both the 32 bit runtime msi  and 64 bit runtime msi to the same location I am publishing to.   If I try to publish with these settings I get the following error messages:

> 1. The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_5.msi' in item 'SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information.
> 2. The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_5.msi' in item 'SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information.
> 3. Cannot publish because a project failed to build.

If I change the prerequisites setting to “Download prerequisites from the component vendor’s web site”. I am able to publish.

On a test machine I first ran the Crystal Reports Runtime (.Net Framework was previously installed on this machine) and then I ran the setup.exe for our application.    The setup.exe cannot install and provides this error message

> Unable to install or run the application.  The application requires
> that assembly CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore Version
> 10.5.3700.0 be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first.  Please contact your system administrator.

We have never had to install this file in the GAC before.

**Am I missing a step to complete the upgrade?**

**Also if I am using Crystal Reports in this method in our application, do I need to do anything with the crystal reports viewer (I have seen downloads for this) or is that only if we are running it outside of the application?**

Comment: You  need to change and or have the correct `Reference` not only have it `GAC'd` but in the .config file as well.. in your current project it's probably still pointing to the old assembly. have you tried removing the old assembly and adding the new one then rebuilding the app prior to deployment..?

Comment: According to the paths on the references, they have been updated:  CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine has a path of: 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86\dotnet\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll`
previously it was a .net framework 2.0 reference.